# Change JFrame background color with JButton not updating

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to make a very simple GUI that updates the background color upon clicking a button. I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong with my code. When it is run nothing updates upon clicking the buttons, any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ChallengeGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JButton blue;
    private JButton red;
    private JButton green;


    public ChallengeGUI() {

        JButton blue = new JButton("BLUE");
        blue.addActionListener(this);
        add(blue);

        JButton red = new JButton("RED");
        red.addActionListener(this);
        add(red);

        JButton green = new JButton("GREEN");
        green.addActionListener(this);
        add(green);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(600,600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == blue) {
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        } else if (e.getSource() == red) {
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
        } else if (e.getSource() == green) {
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ChallengeGUI();

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try setting your content pane to be opaque?

Comment: tried and it didn't seem to make any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one mistake.

- You've shadowed your buttons so e.getSource()==red is always false.

Instead of

```
JButton red = new JButton("RED");
```

just write

```
red = new JButton("RED");
```

When you wrote: `JButton red = ...` it created a local variable named `red` separate from the field declared in your class, also named `red`. That means the field did not get initialized. In your listener, none of the cases were true because `red`, `blue`, and `green` were null and `e.getSource()` was returning the local JButton you created.

Comment: thank you! That solved it! Could you elaborate a bit more on what you mean by shadowed? sorry I am quite a newbie

Comment: @dvas89 You have a field in your class named red, but you declared a local variable named red that essentially hide your field. Later when you referenced the field, it was still null. When you hide a field like that it is sometimes called shadowing.

Comment: Thank you @matt! appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write your `actionPerformed()` method like this:

```java
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
    Color color;
    switch (actionCommand) {
        case "BLUE":
            color = Color.BLUE;
            break;
        case "RED":
            color = Color.RED;
            break;
        case "GREEN":
            color = Color.GREEN;
            break;
        default:
            color = null;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unhandled: " + actionCommand);
    }
    if (color != null) {
        getContentPane().setBackground(color);
    }
}
```